# Trouble getting past CORS error in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-views, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm getting a CORS error whilst trying to use React with Django and postgresql. I have tried many ways to configure the CORS settings in Django however nothing seems to work. When I made a simple route that passes "Hi" it works. So I am not sure if there is an error with my view or something is wrong with the front end at React. I have also ensured that the VITE_SERVER is correct by console logging it and that my endpoints used are accurate.

This are my Django settings:

```
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'content-type',
    'authorization',
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ALL_ORIGINS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/"]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customers.CustomerAccount'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'customers',
    'dealer',
    'restful_apis',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

This is my fetch hook that I used:

```
import React from "react";

const useFetch = () => {
  const fetchData = async (endpoint, method, body, token) => {
    const res = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER + endpoint, {
      //   mode: "no-cors",
      method,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    let returnValue = {};
    if (res.ok) {
      if (data.status === "error") {
        returnValue = { ok: false, data: data.msg };
      } else {
        returnValue = { ok: true, data };
      }
    } else {
      if (data?.errors && Array.isArray(data.errors)) {
        const messages = data.errors.map((item) => item.msg);
        returnValue = { ok: false, data: messages };
      } else if (data?.status === "error") {
        returnValue = { ok: false, data: data.message || data.msg };
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        returnValue = { ok: false, data: "An error has occurred" };
      }
    }

    return returnValue;
  };

  return fetchData;
};

export default useFetch;
```

Here is my view that does not work:

```
 class CarRentalListView(views.APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
def get(self, request):
    rentals = RentalListing.objects.all()
    serialized_data = []

    for rental in rentals:
        rental_data = RentalListingSerializer(rental).data
        car_data = CarSerializer(rental.car_id).data

        combined_data = {
            "rentallisting_id": rental_data.get("id"),
            "rental_rate": rental_data.get("rental_rate"),
            "drive_to_malaysia": rental_data.get("drive_to_malaysia"),
            "listing_date": rental_data.get("listing_date"),
            "vehicle_id": car_data.get("car_id"),
            "brand": car_data.get("brand"),
            "model": car_data.get("model"),
            "colour": car_data.get("colour"),
            "vehicle_type": car_data.get("vehicle_type"),
            "vehicle_image": car_data.get("vehicle_image"),
            "seat_capacity": car_data.get("seat_capacity"),
        }

        serialized_data.append(combined_data)

    return (Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK))
```

Here is the view that works. I am able to receive the data in my browser console:

```
class TestRoute(views.APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

def get(self, request):
    return Response("Hi")
```

Finally on React this is how I am calling the endpoint.(I have checked to see if the endpoints work in Postman and also double checked the enpoints in React):

```
    const Home = () => {
  const fetchData = useFetch();
  const [rentals, setRentals] = useState([]);

  const getRentals = async () => {
    const res = await fetchData("/dealer/cars/rentals", "GET", undefined);
    if (res.ok) {
      setRentals(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRentals();
    console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER);
  }, []);
```

Finally, this is the CORS error my browser throws me:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dealer/cars/rentals' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the CORS error was prevelant only when I used a particular Google account on Chrome. When I switched chrome accounts the data was able to go through to the front end and logged on my chrome developer console. As such upon more digging I found that the solution was to enable ALLOW CORS:Access Control extension in my google chrome browser with the main account I was using.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf